# tables in python - having some errors - not sure why

Tags: python

I have some questions about "technical" and basic functions in python.

I have a table like this:

```
Name,Gender,Age,Salary,Height
Menny,   M,    1,   1,   1
James,   J,    2,   2,   2
Sami,    S,    3,   3,   3


class Table:

def __init__(self,path,sep):
    try:
        f = open(path, "r")
        read_file = f.read()
        f.close()
    except:
        print "cannot create a table from this file"
        return

    table = read_file.split("\n")
    for i in range (len(table)):
        table[i] = table[i].split(sep)

    if len(table) > 0:
        for i in range(len(table[0])):
            if table[0][i] in table[0][0:i]:
                raise ValueError

        row_names = []
        for i in range(1,len(table)):
            if len(table[i]) != len(table[0]):
                raise ValueError
            if table[i][0] in row_names:
                raise ValueError
            row_names.append(table[i][0])
```

Now I want to use functions:
 1. to know how many cells there are. here I have 12 cells. The height of the table is len(table). Then the width is len(table[0]). The number of cells is height*width.
so:

```
    def len(self):
        height = len(table)
        width = len(table[0])
      return height * width
```

and if I tried this:

```
def len(self):
    len(self.nestedList)*len(self.nestedList[0])
```

I get "None"

1. If in the shell I write the name Menny, Sami etc, then print the rest of the line (age, salary etc)....
   So I thought about it:

   ```
   def the_row (self, rowname):
   rows_checking = []
   for i in range(1, len(table)):
       rows_checking.append(table[i])
       if rowname in rows_checking:
           table[i].remove(table[0:0])
           return table[i]
   ```

   1. almost the same thing like in the second task, but this time the function will print the value that is common to 2 thing. For example - the code will print "1" if I write Menny and Age.
      Again, I think I'll do it almost the same as I did in the pre task, but this time:

   get_the_value(self,rowname,colname)

So far seems to be good ideas, I hope so...
but I get errors:

```
AttributeError: Table instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

or

```
AttributeError: Table instance has no attribute 'len'
```

Probably because I didn't used "self" here, right? So what I can do?
You don't have to feed me by the spoon and tell me the codes as it should be, but just give me advices as possible as you can, please.

edited code:

```
class Table:

def __init__(self,path,sep):
    self.path=path
    self.sep=sep
    self.g=[]
    self.count=0
    self.headlines=[]
    self.matrix=[]
    self.headrows=[]
    self.postionrow=0
    self.postioncolmn=0
    try:
        f=open(self.path,'r')

        read_file=f.read()
        split_file=read_file.split()
        for line in split_file:
            list_the_line=line.split(self.sep)
            self.g.append(list_the_line)
        self.count=0    
        for z in range (len(self.g[0])):
            self.count=0 
            for d in range(len(self.g[0])):
                if self.g[0][z]==self.g[0][d]:
                    self.count+=1
            if self.count>=2:
                raise ValueError        




        num_first_line=len(self.g[0])
        for k in range (len(self.g)):
            if len(self.g[k])!= num_first_line:
                raise ValueError

        self.headlines=self.g[0]        
        self.g.remove(self.g[0])

        self.count=0
        for row_name1 in range (len(self.g)):
            self.count=0
            for row_name2 in range(len(self.g)):
                if self.g[row_name1][0]==self.g[row_name2][0]:
                    self.count+=1

            if self.count>=2:
                raise ValueError







        for i in range (len(self.g)):
            self.headrows.append(self.g[i][0])
            self.g[i].remove(self.g[i][0])

        ezer=[]

        for op in range (len(self.g)):
            ezer=[]
            for od in range (len(self.g[0])):
                ezer.append(self.g[od][op])
            self.matrix.append(ezer)    


        f.close()    




    except :
        print "cannot creat a table object from this file"
        return

def len(self):
    num_rows=len(self.g)
    num_cols=len(self.g[0])
    return num_rows*num_cols

def get_row(self,rowname):
    for i in range (len(self.headlines)):
        if rowname==self.headrows[i]:
            self.postionrow=i
            return self.g[i]

    if not rowname in self.headrows :
        raise ValueError
def get_column(self,colname):
    for i in range (len(self.headlines)):
        if colname==self.headlines[i]:
            self.postioncolmn=i-1

            return self.matrix[i-1]

    if not colname in self.headlines :
        raise ValueError
def get_value(self,rowname,colname):
    self.get_row(rowname)
    self.get_column(colname)
    if not rowname in self.headrows :
        raise ValueError
    if not colname in self.headlines :
        raise ValueError

    return self.g[self.postionrow][self.postioncolmn]

def get_row_name_with_max_value(self,colname):
    if not colname in self.headlines :
        raise ValueError
    max_colmn=max(self.get_column(colname))
    for i in range (len(self.matrix)):

        if max_colmn == self.g[i][self.postioncolmn]:

            return self.headrows[i]
```

and what should be the result:

```
>>> table = Table("table_examp1111111","\t")
    cannot create a table from this file 
>>> table = Table("table_example1.txt","\t")             
>>> print table.len() 
    12 
>>> print table.get_row("Menny")
    ['M', '1', '1', '1'] 
>>> print table.get_column("Height") 
    ['1', '2', '3'] 
>>> print table.get_value("Sami","Age")
    3
>>> print table.get_row_name_with_max_value("Height")
    Sami
>>> print table.get_row_name_with_max_value("Salary")
    Sami
```

**This code works but I want to make it more pythonic. Please don't change the form, don't add or remove function just fix my syntex.**
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want len(table) return?

Comment: the quantity of rows I expect

Comment: you could use the standard library csv for this

Comment: Just an observation, but if this is exactly how your code looks, It should be indented after the line 'Class Table:'

Comment: @Totem I didn't  quite understand what you wrote

Comment: Your init method in the class Table is not indented properly. It should be tabbed in the same way you tab in the next line after an if statement etc. I know this may just be a result of accidental formatting in the post.

Comment: @Totem Can you show me please?

Comment: you miss the return keyword of **len** function.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the function len() on an object. It will try to call the __ len__ function of that object. So if you do that it might work.

```
def __len__(self):
    height = len(self.table)
    width = len(self.table[0])
    return height * width
```

Answer (score 0):

you are tying to call `__len__` on the `Table` class, while you look like you should be calling it on your `table` string array in the constructor. 
You should create an attribute `self.table`, and then either use the `len` function on that, or

```
def numOfCells(self): 
    return len(self.table) * len(self.table[0])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crate an atribute self.table"? How?

Comment: Just initialize self.table by assigning a value to it in the constructor, eg `self.table=wtv`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect place to use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

def load_csv(fname, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        in_csv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        return list(in_csv)

class Table:
    def __init__(self, path, sep=','):
        self.table = load_csv(path, delimiter=sep)

        if len(self.table) == 0:
            raise ValueError('No data in file {}'.format(path))

        self.header = self.table.pop(0)
        self.cols   = len(self.header)
        self.labels = {}
        for i, row in enumerate(self.table, 1):
            # make sure rows are all same length
            if len(row) != self.cols:
                raise ValueError('row {} contains {} items - should be {}'.format(i, len(row), self.cols))
            # make sure rows-labels are unique
            lbl = row[0]
            if lbl in self.labels:
                raise ValueError('rows {} and {} - duplicate labels'.format(self.labels[lbl], i))
            else:
                self.labels[lbl] = i - 1

    @property
    def rows(self):
        return len(self.table)

    @property
    def cells(self):
        return self.rows * (self.cols - 1)  # omit row labels

    def get_row_by_label(self, lbl):
        return self.table[self.labels[lbl]]

    def get_item(self, lbl, attr):
        ndx = self.header.index(attr)
        return self.get_row_by_label(lbl)[ndx]

def main():
    t = Table('tbl.csv')
    print(t.cells)
    print(t.get_row_by_label("Menny"))
    print(t.get_item("Menny", "Age"))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, without using the import CSV. Can you think about other options to help me without changing the form as I posted here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Ok, this is for your FIRST question. From what I understand, you are wanting a function that will return the number of cells in your table. This number does not include the names of people in the rows, and does not include the first row at all. If I understand correctly, then this should work:

If table is:

```
Name,Gender,Age,Salary,Height
Menny,   M,    1,   1,   1
James,   J,    2,   2,   2
Sami,    S,    3,   3,   3
```

Then number of cells is `'12'`... so:

Example:

```
class Table:

    def __init__(self, path, sep):
        try:
            with open(path) as f:
                read_file = f.read() # will auto close the file after the read
        except:
            print "cannot create a table from this file"
            return



        self.table = read_file.split('\n') # self.table will make this easier
        self.table = [self.table[i].split(sep) for i in range(len(self.table))] # does the same as your for loop



        if len(self.table) > 0:
            for i in range(len(self.table[0])):
                if self.table[0][i] in self.table[0][0:i]:
                    raise ValueError

        row_names = []
        for i in range(1,len(self.table)):
            if len(self.table[i]) != len(self.table[0]):
                raise ValueError
            if self.table[i][0] in row_names:
                raise ValueError
            row_names.append(self.table[i][0])

       # now a function that could return the table length
   def get_num_cells(self):
       # essentially you sum each item in row[1:] for table[1:]
       return sum((sum(1 for i in range(1, len(self.table[0])))) for i in range(1,len(self.table)))
```

Using `self.table` will make this easier, as you don't have to include it in the other function args, as above in `get_num_cells`, I just used `self.table` without putting it in the args of the function.

To call this function you would do the following:

```
app = Table(path, sep)
app.get_num_cells()
# this code would be placed at the end of your file, and not inside the class
```

Example:

```
class Table()

    __init__(self, path, sep):
        etc.

   etc.etc.etc.

# now the code to create an instance of Table and call a method here like this
app = Table(path, sep) # path would be a filepath "C:/etc./file.txt", and sep = "," etc.
app.get_num_cells()
```

For your other questions, I am not entirely sure what you want yet, but if you write again in the comments for this, I will try. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It just a mistakein the post here, but good that you have notice that. Can you help me in the other questions (done with the len)?

Comment: Is your main question basically 'how to make a function to return how many cells?'

Comment: There are 3 main questions.

Comment: I get this error: "self.table = [self.table[i].split(sep) for i in range(len(self.table))] # does the same as your for loop
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: self.table[i] should not be a list because self.table should look like this ['item, item, item, item', 'item, item, item, item',etc.] so each i in self.table is a string, and split should work on it.

Comment: What if I want that the paer "app = Table(path, sep)" will be in the code and not the in the shell? I get errors that path is not defined if I do that...

Comment: path was just a placeholder. You yourself wrote the init method with the args path and sep. path must be replaced by the path of the file you wanted to open... as in app = Table("/filpath.yourfile.txt", ","). those args get passed to init

Comment: But still I don't get it, where should I put it in the code if not in the shell?

Comment: app = Table(path, sep) would be placed at the end of your file most likely, and not inside the class

Comment: I mean, where I should put the line "app = Table(path, sep)" in the code at your post, that u've edited? I don't understand

Comment: please let me know if this makes sense to you

Comment: I mean just the line of "app = Table(path, sep)" without the line of "app.get_num_cells()"... Can it be?

Comment: yeah, just add it in the end of the .py file like I show at the end of my post. I am really not sure what you want though.

Comment: Dear sir, look at my post again please. I've coded again a new code and it's works but it's too long, not pythonic and I think that some lines could be removed but I've not idea which. So please, I would like if you will check my code and change it but liik at the note - don't change the function. Thanks!!!!